# `out` `ref` 'this' in C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to `C#`, just a few days of starting. I want to know what is the exact usage of `out` `ref` `this`  and any other keyword used with parameters and what they really do. It would be very helpful if you can compare them with `VB.Net`'s.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: If you're learning it from a decent source, you'll learn about each it in time, when it fits your progress. Why so impatient?

Comment: Please buy a book. If you have specific problems, post them here with your efforts to understand them.

Comment: Before buying a book, you might want to simply read the [C# specification](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F3%2F8%2F8%2F388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09%2Fcsharp%2520language%2520specification.doc&rct=j&q=c%23%20specification&ei=RTs1Ts2PM4a88gOq4_SgDg&usg=AFQjCNGXik09_Rn-k0FGHG-A6v1EX3RLyA).

Comment: Already downvotes ! now more ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `out` and `ref` correspond to `ByRef` in VB.NET. The distinction between the two is that `out` signals to the compiler that the parameter is used for *output only*. That means that it doesn’t need to have a meaningful value beforehand (i.e. it doesn’t need to be initialised). The compiler would complain otherwise.

  In VB, this isn’t relevant: variables that aren’t explicitly initialised are initialised automatically: `Dim i As Integer` will set `i` to `0`.
- `this` is used for extension methods and corresponds to using the [`Extension` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) in VB.
- Lastly, there’s `params` which corresponds to `ParamArray` in VB, and is used in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

out and ref are ways to passing parameters to methods by reference not by value. If you send a parameter by value (without prefixing it name with ref or out) any changes to parameter in called method body wont change original sent parameter. But by sending paramter through ref or out, any changes in called method body will change original sent paramter.

About 'this'. whenever you call some method or field by using this, you actually accessing class fields or methods.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) a list of all the c# keywords. But to explain the ones you've mentioned specifically.

- "this"; VB.net equivalent: "Me". Allows access to the instance from within the instance.
- "ref"; VB.net equivalent: "ByRef". Passes a value by reference to a function, as opposed to a copy of it. This is true only for value types (structs, int, double, byte etc). Passing a reference type (a class/object) with the ref parameter means you are making the pointer to the object modifiable.
- "out"; VB.net equivalnt: unsure, perhaps ByRef. Allows a function to place a value into a specific variable that the caller passes to the function. Meaning that the variable does not first need to initialize to a default value, as the function declared with an out param is required to initialize it for the caller.

[Comparing VB.Net and C#](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) may be useful to you.